# If a regression problem is ill-conditioned, does that mean we cannot perform SGD? What happens if we do?

Tags: regression, optimization, multicollinearity, loss-functions, gradient-descent

By ill-conditioned regression problem, I mean that the feature matrix $X$ is not full rank. For example, X contains two or more columns highly correlated. If that's the case, $X^T\cdot X$ is not invertible, which means we cannot compute the closed-form solution.

My understanding is that we cannot perform Stochastic gradient descent either. However, I don't know the proper explanation. Does that mean that the loss landscape is not convex? and what would happen if we apply the SGD? Would the algorithm converge to a local minimum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SGD has nothing to do with this problem. No estimation method can resolve this issue because a singular $X^\top X$ means the solution to the system of equations is not unique.

SGD converges at a rate proportional to the condition number of the inverse of your Hessian matrix (which in your case does not exist). This means your condition number is somewhere very close to zero, and so is your convergence rate.

Comment: Thanks, does that mean that if we apply SGD we will converge to local optima?

Comment: @lalaland I've edited my answer to address your comment.

Comment: I appreciate it. Can I just finally ask what does the condition number mean? Thanks again

Comment: @lalaland You used the word *ill-conditioned* in your question. That comes from [*condition number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number), i.e., ill-conditioned when the condition number is very high.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate your patience